# Wait until an HTML5 video loads-Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, html5-video, html-input

I have a video tag, that I dynamically change its source as I am letting the user to choose from a number of videos from the database. The problem is that, i am getting error while calling the load function

Here is my code:

```
var video = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('introVideo');
video.src = this.videoUrl;
video.load();`
```

But doing so i am getting a warning

> [ts] Property load does not exists on type **HTMLInputElement**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test this, but try casting your HTML element to a `HTMLVideoElement` instead of `HTMLInputElement` because the method `.load()` does not exist on `HTMLInputElement` type.

Cheers.